# Issue in rendering data in table as per the number input

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to apply input number ng-model as the length of below table.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myObj =[ {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
    
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
Display Rows in Table : <input type="number" ng-model="numberOfRows"/>
<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="x in myObj">
  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
  <td>{{x.City}}</td>  
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best and easiest solution is to use `limitTo` filter. This is a AngularJS native filter that limit iterated results in `ngRepeat`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myObj =[ {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
      {"Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Country" : "Germany","City" : "Berlin"},
    
    ]

$scope.numberOfRows = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Display rows in Table : <input type="number" min="0" max="{{myObj.length}}" ng-model="numberOfRows"/>
  <table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myObj | limitTo:numberOfRows">
      <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
      <td>{{x.City}}</td>  
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what would make `numberOfRows` default back to max length when input field is empty?

Comment: need to display 1 record default

Comment: See edited example. You missed one thing: numberOfRows was outside of controller. Now it's working with default value set to one

Comment: @SamudralaRamu, never mind, got it: `limitTo: numberOfRows ? numberOfRows : 1`

Comment: @Zooly if you would delete that 1 from input field it goes back to empty table

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Maybe in this case this isn't a problem? I don't really know so I prefer stay simple as possible. But your ternary solution is a good solution with we want to display at least one value